# Añadir un dato si hay coincidencia

Tags: r

Tengo los dos siguientes df:

```
    d1=data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
                  col2=c("rojo","verde","amarillo","amarillo 23","pepe","marta","lento"),
                  col3=c(150,250,50,100,300,125,200))
    
    d2=data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,4),
                  col2=c("morado","rojo","amarillo 23","marta"),
                  col3=c(165,165,100,95))
    d2$prueba<-NA
```

Busco hacer:

Si un elemento del d2$col2 está en d1$col2 que añada en d2$prueba el valor de su posición en
d1%col1 (que no tiene por qué estar en orden)

El resultado buscado es algo como esto

```
  col1        col2     prueba
    1      morado     No está
    2        rojo        1
    3 amarillo 23        4
    4       marta        6
```

Con este código y sus variantes no consigo que salga.

```
for (i in d2$col2)
  (j in 1:length(d2$col2))
  {
d2[j,"prueba"]<-ifelse(i %in% d1$col2, which(i == d1$col2) , "No está")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si existe una coincidencia 1 a 1, la forma más sencilla es:

```
d2$prueba[d2$col2 %in% d1$col2] <- which(d1$col2 %in% d2$col2)
```

---

Modificamos las filas dónde `d2$col` coincide con `d1$col` y le asignamos el valor posicional de los valores de `d1$col2` que coinciden con `d2$col2`.

Esto no funciona si eventualmente por cada caso tuvieras más de una coincidencia, en dicho caso podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
library(tidyverse)

d2 %>% 
  left_join(d1 %>%
              mutate(n=row_number()), 
            by="col2",
            suffix=c("", ".y")) %>% 
  group_by(col1, col2, col3) %>% 
  summarise(prueba = paste0(n, collapse = ","))
```

---

En este caso, si tuvieras más de una coincidencia, terminaríamos concatenando todas las posiciones, separadas por coma.