# Identificar registros por el ID

Tags: r

Esta pregunta se me ha hecho un poco larga, pero en realidad creo que es fácil (para el que sepa)

Tengo 3 df

```
d1=data.frame(Modelo = sample(c("ModeloA","ModeloB","ModeloC","ModeloD"), 20, replace=TRUE),
              Color = sample(c("ColorA","ColorB","ColorC"), 20, replace=TRUE),
              Distancia = sample(100:300, 20, replace=TRUE),
              Id=1:20)

d2=data.frame(Modelo = sample(c("ModeloD","ModeloB","ModeloE","ModeloD"), 30, replace=TRUE),
              Color = sample(c("ColorA","ColorF","ColorC"), 30, replace=TRUE),
              Distancia = sample(120:260, 30, replace=TRUE),
              Id=1:30)

d3=data.frame(Modelo = sample(c("ModeloA","ModeloB","ModeloD"), 20, replace=TRUE),
              Color = sample(c("ColorA","ColorB","ColorC","ColorD"), 20, replace=TRUE),
              Distancia = sample(120:200, 20, replace=TRUE),
              Id=1:20)
```

Quiero identificar los registros que coincidan en las 3 bases y que me indique en que ID está de cada base (filtrando los datos según cierta distancia)

**Primero unifico los 3 df**

```
col<-c("Modelo", "Color")
```

- Unifico df1 con df2

  ```
  d1 %>% inner_join(d2,by=col, suffix=c(".d1", ".d2"))-> d1_2
  ```
- Unifico df1_2 con df3

```
    d1_2 %>% inner_join(d3,by=col) -> d12_3
```

Renombro el ID para dejar claro que es el id3. (No consigo que se cambie en el paso anterior)

```
d12_3 <-rename(d12_3, c("Id.d3"="Id"))
```

Ya tengo los 3df unificados en uno solo.

Ahora, partiendo de la columna Distancia, los datos que están a una distancia entre sí de más de 100 con respecto a cualquier de los otros los descarto.

Para compararlos, lo que se me ha ocurrido es buscar la distancia mínima e ir comparando cada df con esa distancia mínima. Si esta a más de 100 lo descarto.
Lo mismo hay una manera mejor de hacerlo.

**Distancia mínima**

```
d12_3$min<-apply(d12_3[, c("Distancia.d1","Distancia.d2","Distancia")], 1, min)
```

Si la distancia de cada df está a más de 100 descarto ese registro.

```
d12_3[abs(d12_3[,"Distancia.d1"]-d12_3[,"min"])<=100,]->d12_3

d12_3[abs(d12_3[,"Distancia.d2"]-d12_3[,"min"])<=100,]->d12_3

d12_3[abs(d12_3[,"Distancia"]-d12_3[,"min"])<=100,]->d12_3
```

Ahora como sé que todos los datos están a menos de 100, la variable distancia ya no me importa. Me quedo con modelo y color.

**Obtener el ID**

Quiero obtener en que id de cada df está cada registro.

Algo como esto

```
Modelo      Color        id.d1        id.d2          id.d3
ModeloD      ColorC       2        6,7,12,15...        14,17
```

El modeloD con colorc es el registro 2 en el df1, que coindice con los registros 6,7,12... del df2 que coincide con los registros 14,17 del df3.

Supongo que hay que agrupar y luego aplicar dos summarise para sacar los id, pero no lo consigo.

Comment: Pregunta, lo que descartas es aquellos registros que están a una distancia mayor de 100 de cualquier de los otros registros de cualquier de los 3 data.frames?

Comment: Sí, descarto aquellos registros de las 3 columnas "distancia" que estén a más de 100 entre ellos. Para compararlos entre sí me he basado en el mínimo como punto de referencia.

Comment: ok, para esa parte no seria necesario no solo compararlo con el mínimo si no tendrías que comparar cada uno de los registros con cada uno de los registros de las siguientes columnas por que no solamente el dato mínimo pudiera estar a un distancia mayor, ya que  también podrían ser otro dato, podrir usar la función apply(d12_3,c(1,2),function(x) ...), para que comparara cada registro

Comment: Había pensado calcular el máximo y el mínimo y ver si la diferencia supera los 100

Comment: Es una buena idea si la diferencia si no cumple la diferencia con el mínimo tampoco cumpliría con cualquier otro valor

Comment: mi ultima duda entonces necesitas que todos queden sobre una misma fila, es decir concatenar los valores para que se agrupen en una fila?

Comment: En una misma fila o en un df. Es parecido a esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/427158/a%c3%b1adir-un-dato-si-hay-coincidencia/427164#427164  pero resumiendo los datos en dos columnas en vez de una.

Comment: es aplicar un group_by y luego un summarise con  paste0(n, collapse = ",")) pero de forma que se resuman los datos en dos columnas en vez de en una.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todo pero en un único lote de código:

```
d1 %>% 
  rename(id1 = Id, Distancia1 = Distancia) %>% 
  inner_join(d2 %>% rename(id2 = Id, Distancia2 = Distancia), by=c("Modelo", "Color")) %>% 
  inner_join(d3 %>% rename(id3 = Id, Distancia3 = Distancia), by=c("Modelo", "Color")) %>% 
  filter(abs(Distancia1-Distancia2) <= 100,
         abs(Distancia1-Distancia3) <= 100,
         abs(Distancia2-Distancia3) <= 100
         ) %>% 
  group_by(Modelo, Color) %>% 
  summarise(id1=paste(unique(id1), collapse=', '),
            id2=paste(unique(id2), collapse=', '),
            id3=paste(unique(id3), collapse=', ')
  )

# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   Modelo [2]
  Modelo  Color  id1      id2           id3             
  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>    <chr>         <chr>           
1 ModeloB ColorA 15       8             2, 8, 11, 14, 18
2 ModeloB ColorC 3, 7, 10 6, 16, 21, 24 10              
3 ModeloD ColorA 8, 13    25, 26        19              
4 ModeloD ColorC 6        3, 7, 13, 14  17
```

Notas:

- renombramos de entrada las columnas `Distancia` y `Id`
- filtramos las combinaciones deseadas con `filter()`
- Por último agrupamos y concatenamos los `id` de cada `data.frame` original

Answer (score 1):

Lo mas cercano que pude obtener a los que deseas es usando el siguiente código:

```
#Nos quedamos con las filas que nos interesan
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
#Nos quedamos con las columnas que nos importan
d12_3_L<-d12_3[c("Modelo","Color","Id.d1","Id.d2","Id.d3")] %>%   
     pivot_longer(c("Id.d1","Id.d2","Id.d3"),names_to="ID",values_to="valores") %>%
     split(list(.$Modelo,.$Color,.$ID)) %>%
     map(function(x) x %>% distinct(Modelo,Color,ID,valores)) %>%
     map(function(x) unite(x,"aux",ID,valores,remove = FALSE,sep=",")) %>%
     map(function(x) x %>% pivot_wider(names_from = aux,values_from=valores)) %>%
     map(function(x) unite(x,"id_n",4:ncol(x),sep=",")) %>%
     bind_rows()


# A tibble: 9 x 4
Modelo  Color  ID    id_n               
<chr>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>              
1 ModeloD ColorA Id.d1 11                 
2 ModeloB ColorC Id.d1 6,12               
3 ModeloD ColorC Id.d1 1,13,15,18         
4 ModeloD ColorA Id.d2 3,12,13,18,19,22,28
5 ModeloB ColorC Id.d2 2,5,8,23,30        
6 ModeloD ColorC Id.d2 6,27,29,4          
7 ModeloD ColorA Id.d3 1,5,9,20           
8 ModeloB ColorC Id.d3 2,6                
9 ModeloD ColorC Id.d3 14,4
```

El código es un poco complicado pero en esencia lo que realiza es primero cambiar la forma de la tabla inicial que se crea con el código que nos compartes , de un formato ancho a uno largo , luego separamos la base en varias bases dependiendo del modelo el color y el ID , esto nos ayuda a unir los id , después creamos una variable auxiliar que nos ayudara al momento de pasar cada data.frame que tenemos en las lista que creamos en el split, y tener argumento únicos , al final solo unimos las filas y nos da el resultado mostrado
te recomiendo que ejecutes línea a línea para que así puedas ir siguiendo lo que realiza el código

Answer (score 0):

otra posible solucion

```
d12_3 %>% 
  group_by(Modelo, Color) %>% 
  summarise(
    Id.d1 = toString(unique(Id.d1)),
    Id.d2 = toString(unique(Id.d2)),
    Id.d3 = toString(unique(Id.d3))
  )
```